# Is a String with no parantheses considered having balanced parantheses?

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata

Say I have a language over the alphabet {x,y,(,)} . The language's rules are: any string over that alphabet with balanced parentheses.

Clearly    x(),  (xy)  , ()()xxx, ((xx)) are accepted. BUT

My question is, is a string with **no** parentheses considered as having balanced parentheses? For example are:   y, xxyy, xyxyxxx  accepted?

And then also what about an empty String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what formal definitions are for...

That said, it makes the most sense to allow no parentheses. Roughly speaking, a string has balanced parentheses if every left parenthesis is "matched" by a right parenthesis (of course this is far from being a formal definition). If there is no left parenthesis, then everything is OK.

Once you accept that, there is absolutely nothing wrong about the empty string – it is a string like any other. In particular, it is a string over your alphabet with balanced parentheses.

One way to formally define your language is using a context-free grammar. While there are many possible grammars, here is one that tried to capture the "matching" aspect when scanning the string from left to right:

$$
\begin{align*}
&S \to \epsilon \\
&S \to xS \\
&S \to yS \\
&S \to (S)S
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't given a formal definition unfortunately, but in (roughly) the wording I stated in my OP. The real question is to design the PDA from the CFG. But - that I will do on my own, just couldn't figure out the "corner case" scenario I was pondering. Thanks!